# On Windows 10 I can't right button drag a file into an email any more

Tags: windows-10, microsoft-outlook-2010

On Windows 7 and Outlook 2010 I would drag a file using the right mouse button onto an Outlook email and when I let the button go be given the choice of attaching or creating a hyperlink. Since I upgraded to Windows 10 this no longer happens. How can I create a hyperlink easily?

Answer (score 0):

Open the file and then close it.
In the email press ctrl-K to open the hyperlink dialog. Your file will be in the list of recently used files (if it's an office document), and you can select it there.